# The number of ways that $2^n +3^n + 5^n$ divisible by $4$ for $n = \{ 1,2,3,4,\ldots,100\}$

Tags: combinatorics

the number of ways that $2^n +3^n + 5^n$ divisible by $4$ for $n = \{ 1,2,3,4,\ldots,100\}$

I have attempted the question by using simple pattern method that leaving aside 1 , all other odd values of ***n*** satisfy the given condition so number of odd numbers from 1 to 100 excluding 1 is 49.

But I need an approach to this question using combinatorics concept. Please provide an approach to this question using combinatorics

Comment: i dont think this is a combinatoric problem , it is number theory based

Comment: I have encountered this question in  the worksheet based on combinatorics concept

Comment: The mention of "number of ways" is rather cryptic. There is only one way. $2^{33}+3^{33}+5^{33}$ is either divisible by 4, or not (I didn't check); so is any other of these numbers.

Comment: You have following combinations - $2^n$ gives remainder of $2$ or $0$. $3^n$ gives remainder of $1$ or $3$. $5^n$ gives remainder of $1$. To be divisible, you can choose $n$ in ways that the remainder is $(0 + 3 + 1)$ or $(2 + 1 + 1)$